# How can I create a signature for AWS in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, hmac, mechanicalturk

I am trying to create the signature for AWS Mechanical Turk, using Node.js, but am having trouble doing so.  At the moment I am using the following, but keep getting errors:

```
CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(service + operation + timestamp, process.env.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY);
```

The explanation of the signature is at this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMechanicalTurkRequester/MakingRequests_RequestAuthenticationArticle.html).  It states that to create a signature

> A request signature, an HMAC, is calculated by concatenating the
>   values of the Service, Operation, and Timestamp parameters, in that
>   order, and then calculating an RFC 2104-compliant HMAC, using the
>   Secret Access Key as the "key." The computed HMAC value should be
>   base64 encoded, and is passed as the value of the Signature request
>   parameter. For more information, go to
>   http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2104.html.

Comment: Looks right. Make sure timestamp is in the `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ` format and that you're base64 encoding the HMAC. Do you need to convert the HMAC to a string variable? (Sorry, I'm not a JS expert).

Comment: @Thomas the thing is that the timestamp looks to be right.  I then do base 64 encoding, but still get an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this will work for you (I use `GetAccountBalance`) as a simple example:

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.0.2/build/rollups/hmac-sha1.js"></script>  
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.0.2/build/components/enc-base64-min.js"></script>  
<script>
var service = "AWSMechanicalTurkRequester";
var timestamp = new Date().toISOString();
var operation = "GetAccountBalance";
var secret = "YOURSECRETKEY";
var signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(service + operation + timestamp, secret).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
</script>
```