# Making requests to Amazon web services REST APIs, cannot get the request Signature to work

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, request, hmac, cryptojs

So I am attempting to make a request to Amazon's product API but I cannot figure out how to get the signature to work.  I was following another stack overflow post that can be found here: [How can I create a signature for AWS in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26915864/how-can-i-create-a-signature-for-aws-in-javascript), but still cannot fulfill my request.  Here is the request that I am sending, (currently testing through postman).

`http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService&AWSAccessKeyId=[MY_ACCESSKEY]&Operation=ItemSearch&Keywords=the%20hunger%20games&SearchIndex=Books &Timestamp=2016-09-09T12:00:00Z&Signature=9RTSas234dfRTs3R%ErA8%`

I made up a fake signature similar to the one that I get from this function:

```
let service = "AWSECommerceService";
let timestamp = "2016-09-09T12:00:00Z";
let operation = "ItemSearch";
let secret = "MY_AMAZONSECRET";
let signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(service + operation + timestamp, secret).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
console.log(signature);
```

The result that logs to the console looks like this: `9RTSas234dfRTs3R+ErA8=`

From what I read here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/rest-signature.html, I thought you needed to replace '+' and '=' to '%' signs.  When I leave the + and = signs as is, I get the following response from AWS:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ItemSearchErrorResponse xmlns="http://ecs.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/">
    <Error>
        <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
        <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.</Message>
    </Error>
    <RequestId>{MY_REQUESTID}</RequestId>
</ItemSearchErrorResponse>
```

But when I change them to %'s, I get this response:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ItemSearchErrorResponse xmlns="http://ecs.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/">
    <Error>
        <Code>MissingParameter</Code>
        <Message>The request must contain the parameter Signature.</Message>
    </Error>
    <RequestId>{MY_REQUESTID}</RequestId>
</ItemSearchErrorResponse>
```

Even though the Signature parameter exists in the request.  Any thoughts on how I can fix this.  I am using crypto-js to create the signature, which can be found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js

Comment: Disregard the MTurk answer you found -- that appears to be an entirely different signature algorithm, not relevant here.  Read through [the page you linked to](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/rest-signature.html) again.  Follow those steps exactly.  Your code is not doing what's described there.

Answer (score 0):

> I thought you needed to replace '+' and '=' to '%' signs.

Yes, but you don't just replace them with `%`.  Use this map:

```
+ becomes %2B
/ becomes %2F
= becomes %3D
```

This is referred to as url-encoding, url-escaping, or percent-encoding.  The characters are replaced by a literal `%` followed by their 2-digit hex ASCII equivalent.

```
9RTSas234dfRTs3R+ErA8= becomes 
9RTSas234dfRTs3R%2BErA8%3D
```

Comment: I tried this and it is still telling me that the Signature does not match.  Could it be the way I am generating the date? Because all I am doing is entering it in manually to the function like this: `2016-09-10T12:00:00Z`

Should I be using something else to generate the date?